# Why does this program crash when freeing?

Tags: c, memory, free, allocation

I'm trying to understand why does this program crash, when I use this line and trying to free the pointer:

```
 t_mat *C=malloc(sizeof(t_mat));
```

But works well with the following line (no memory leaks, no crashing, the value 53 is the minimum I found by trial and error):

```
 t_mat *C=malloc(sizeof(t_mat)+53);
```

Program: (the while(1) loop is for memory leak testing, doesn't affect the crashing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
typedef int t_mat[3][3];
t_mat* matice(t_mat A, t_mat B, char op)
{
    t_mat *C=malloc(sizeof(t_mat)+53);
    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                *C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
        return *C;
        break;
    case '-':
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                *C[i][j]=A[i][j]-B[i][j];
        return *C;
        break;
    default:
        free(C);
        printf("Chyba\n");
        return NULL;
        break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char op;
    scanf("%c",&op);
    getchar();
    t_mat A = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},B= {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},*C;
    while(1)
    {
        C=matice(A, B, op);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                printf("%d\n",*C[i][j]);
        free(C);
        C=NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Try running your program under valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Please use consistent indentation for your code, it will make it easier to read, follow along in, understand, and (for you) maintain.

Comment: And I'll bet if you use a debugger to catch the crash, it will stop not of the `free` call but on the `printf` call where you use the dereference operator wrongly.

Comment: Did you notice any warnings when compiling this code? I saw two important ones after adding the two includes you should have shown in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unary `*` has lower precedence than `[]`.  You need to write `(*C)[i][j]`.

Comment: Hmm, Haven't thought about that... 
But why with extra 53 bytes it works the wrong way ?

Comment: @PanJa: Try doing the pointer arithmetic by hand to see which address `*C[i][j]` was actually accessing.

Comment: @PanJa: But in general, when a bug in a C program causes undefined behavior, it's very common that unrelated changes can stop the bug from appearing.  That doesn't mean it's fixed because it may come back again with other unrelated changes.  You can't assume that just because a program works now, it's fixed; you have to understand what was wrong and how to fix it correctly.

Comment: Don't worry I know what you are saying ! 
I thought it was solely memory allocation related,so I have focused all my attention to that, but it wasn't... But is there any other way to learn anything without tripping a few times ?

Comment: @PanJa: For future reference, a crash when freeing nearly always means you have written outside the bounds of a `malloc`ed block of memory (not necessarily the same one you are freeing!) and overwritten malloc's internal data; or else that you have freed the same block twice.  Increasing the size probably meant that the place you wrote was back inside the bounds, or at least that what it happened to overwrite didn't touch malloc's data.

Answer (score 0):

Statements like these

```
*C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
```

and

```
printf("%d\n",*C[i][j]);
```

invoke undefined behavior. The type of the variable `C` is `int ( * )[3][3]` due to this declaration

```
t_mat *C=malloc(sizeof(t_mat)+53);
```

So at first you shall to apply the dereferencing operator and only after that the subscript operator

```
( *C )[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
```

or

```
printf("%d\n", ( *C )[i][j]);
```

Otherwise the program has undefined behavior.

So there is no any sense to use the magic number `53` in the memory allocation. Just write

```
t_mat *C=malloc(sizeof(t_mat));
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N   3
typedef int t_mat[N][N];

int main(void) 
{
    t_mat A = 
    { 
        { 0, 1, 2 }, 
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8 }
    };
    
    t_mat B = 
    { 
        { 0, 1, 2 }, 
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8 }
    };
    
    t_mat *C = malloc( sizeof( t_mat ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            ( *C )[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", ( *C )[i][j] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    free( C );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 0  2  4 
 6  8 10 
12 14 16
```

Comment: Thanks !  The missing parantheses was the problem